# Showing Application Icon while sharing Images / messages on social Network

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 8 /7 Application . Its basically an Image Editing Suite. What Exactly I want is that I want to share the pic on facebook /twitter but I dont want that Windows Phone Violet icon appearing while the image is shared.
What I want is that my custom Application icon occurs there.
I want something like this ( via XYZ Application(followed by the custom icon) .
how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement sharing by your self. The built-in sharing does not allow you to share images anyway (just image links)